# how to write handleCredentialResponse function in Typescript and Angular version 14 for <<Sign in with Google>>

Tags: angular, typescript

I am building a very basic angular version 14 app which display a 'Sign in with Google button' and implement login.

The documentation for new way of **Sign in With Google** is
https://developers.google.com/identity/gsi/web/guides/overview

Google has deprecated the older version for 'Sign in with Google'.

It has two component, one to add html to display 'Sign in Google' button.
Though I had to load the script dynamically

```
https://accounts.google.com/gsi/client
```

Add add the html to display Google sign button

**login.component.html**

```
<h4>Login works!</h4>
<html>
  <body>
      <div id="g_id_onload"
         data-client_id="xxxxxxxx.apps.googleusercontent.com"   
         data-callback="handleCredentialResponse">
      </div>
      <div class="g_id_signin"
         data-type="standard"
         data-size="large"
         data-theme="outline"
         data-text="sign_in_with"
         data-shape="rectangular"
         data-logo_alignment="left">
      </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

A callback function to handle credential response has been defined above as

```
data-callback="handleCredentialResponse"
```

Second Add the callback function definition into login.component.ts

```
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {
  handleCredentialResponse(response: any){
    console.log("handleCredentialResponse called.");
  }
  //some other methods...
}
```

**Issue:** Angular complains about the callback function handleCredentialResponse as shown in the attached screenshot.
Error Message:

```
[GSI_LOGGER]: The value of 'callback' is not a function. Configuration ignored.
```

[image]

**Question:** Does anyone know how to write this callback function **handleCredentialResponse** in typescript/angular?

I am not in frontend development, so if someone could help with the implementation, that would be a great help.

Comment: Not sure if useful but checkout the AngularFire package

Answer (score 0):

In this case handleCredentialResponse is global function which can only be reffered through window object. Please create angular service or listener which make refference to window object then you will to refer and define this callback handleCredentialResponse.